# How to Avoid default Selected from dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

In my current code we have a drop down lists similar like below which is a mandatory field earlier  so we need to select the value before submitting the form but now there is no need mandatory so removed the Mandatory check condition and current code as below.

```
         <asp:dropdownlist id="ddlTest" Runat="server" TabIndex="01">
          <asp:ListItem Selected="True" ">Select</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="N" >No</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="Y">Yes</asp:ListItem>
     </asp:dropdownlist>

         prmddlTest.Value = Format_SQL(ddlTest.SelectedItem.Value)
          cmdSaveData.Parameters.Add(prmddlTest)
                                   
            Function Format_SQL(ByVal sInput) As Object
                                    If sInput = "" Or sInput = "-1" Then
                                    Return DBNull.Value
                                    Else
                                    Return sInput
                                    End If
                                    End Function
```

I am getting error during submit the form because of default "Select" If I select No or Yes value going fine. How to avoid "Select" in code during submission.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<asp:dropdownlist id="ddlTest" Runat="server" TabIndex="01">
    <asp:ListItem  Text="" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="N" >No</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Y">Yes</asp:ListItem>
</asp:dropdownlist>
```

Comment: Thanks but why the value goes as starting value "N"

Comment: So, try to add an empty value in this line: <asp:ListItem  Text="" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>                   
like this:  <asp:ListItem  Value="" Text="" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>